# synchronized method that use a public static HashTable from other class. How can I make this method thread safe?

Tags: java, thread-safety

suppose I have a synchronized method that use a public static HashTable from other class. How can I make this method thread safe ? for my understanding any other thread can change this HashTable as it in other class and not in the class that holds the key (the class of the synchronized method) , doesn't it ?

Comment: Use a synchronized collections such as ConcurrentHashMap/HashSet

Comment: `Hashtable` is already synchronized.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding about the HashTable is not correct. HashTable is Synchronized and thread safe.

Look into the source code of `HashTable`. All the public methods are synchronized.

```
public synchronized V put(K key, V value) {

public synchronized V get(Object key) { 
public synchronized boolean contains(Object value) {
```

Comment: thank you . And if the map is in the same class of the synchronized method and the map is private , can I use HashMap instead ? no other thread can change it when used by the synchronized method ?

Comment: HashMap is not synchronized. If you want to synchronize you can use 

`Collections.synchronizedMap(map);` and  do the stuff inside synchronized block. Refer this : http://java67.blogspot.in/2015/02/how-to-synchronize-hashmap-in-java-with.html

Comment: Collections.synchronizedMap makes method calls atomic, it does not make it fully threadsafe and still you need the synchronization block. I would prefer `ConcurrentHashMap`for thread safe operations.

Comment: this is not my qwestion . if the map is in the **same** class of the synchronized method and the map is **private** , can I use HashMap instead ? no other thread can change it when used by the **synchronized method** ?

Comment: If you are using the map internally only in synchronized block ,then you can!. Make sure you doesn't provide the way to access the map outside.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your *HashMap* inside your synchronized method, it can work but only if all threads use the same instance of the class that contains both the method and the *HashMap*, for more clarity take a look at the example bellow :

**Code Snippet**

```
public class SynchronizedCounter {
    private int c = 0;

    public synchronized void increment() {
        c++;
    }
}
```

Now if all the threads use the same instance of *SynchronizedCounter*, we make sure only one thread is running the `increment()` method at time, but if each thread is instantiating his own SynchronizedCounter instance then the method won't be thread safe.

Oracle's official description [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html).

Comment: but c is not static and it is private in your example .. so what is the problem?it is thread safe , no ?

Comment: and if it was static public we have to use Atomic Integer , no ?

Comment: Event if your HashMap is static this won't change the behavior of synchronized method, if your threads use the same instance of the class that contains your HashMap, then the synchronized method will allow only one thread to run the function at time, however, if they use different instances then the method won't block the other threads,  regardless of whether your HashMap is static or not.

Comment: No cause the HashMap is static, so it will be the same of all instances.

Comment: yes I mean if it is not static ..so if it is static it is important to use same instanace and if not it is not important

Comment: Not really, cause if all the threads are using the same HashMap instance, and the HashMap is not static you still have to use same instance of the class containing the HashMap.